# How to consume ajax returned json data in DataTables and have a form in each row

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, datatables

I want to consume ajax returned data in my **JQuery DataTables**. I have created loop to view every row and also need to add a view button for them. I pass all data to **JQuery DataTables**. I cannot understand how to do that.

This is my `ajax` request

```
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#searchArea").show();
            var uID = $("#userName").val();

            var tableProduct = $('#dataTbl').DataTable({
                "bSort": false
                , "oLanguage": {"sZeroRecords": "", "sEmptyTable": ""}
            });
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/restservice/viewApplication/' + uID,
                success: function (result) {
                    var jString = JSON.stringify(result);
                    var jdata = JSON.parse(jString);

                    for (var x = 0; x < jdata.length; x++) {

                        var td1 = jdata[x].snumber;
                        var td2 = jdata[x].date;
                        var td3 = jdata[x].slsNo + " in " + jdata[x].slsiUnit;
                        var td4 = jdata[x].productDesc;
                        var td5 = jdata[x].status;
                        var td6 = "view btn1";
                        var td7 = "view btn2";
                        var td8 = "view btn3";
                        tableProduct.row.add([td1, td2, td3, td4, td5, td6, td7, td8]).draw(true);
                    }
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
```

I want to add this code for every row. How can I do that ?

```
 <form method="post" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/viewApplication" target="_blank">
     <input type="hidden" name="snumber" value="jdata[x].snumber"/>
     <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" value="View" />
     <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
 </form>
```

Comment: jquery DataTable can handle json very well and can populate your rows with those json data. Do you aware of that ?

Comment: I want to add form data to each row

Comment: Do you aware of  Ajax sourced data handling in datatables ? see  https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

Answer (score 0):

### Consuming Ajax data in DataTables

There is already a handy feature in **DataTables** to fetch data from ajax and consume them as you configure your table. Just use the `ajax` option and tell about the data source you want to consume

```
$('#dataList').DataTable({
    ajax: {
            url: 'url',
            type: 'GET',
            dataSrc: ''
    }
}
```

See this [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) for complete guideline.

**Note:** here passing `dataSrc` option as *empty* tells dataTable to expect an array rather than objects from ajax response

Following is a example that depicts a senario where datatable is configured to consume a api response. For demonastration purpose I used a public dummy api service that returned an json array. See [this](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos) dummy api response.

```js
$(function() {
  var columnArray = [{
      title: "Photo ID",
      data: "id",
      targets: 0
    },
    {
      title: "Photo Title",
      data: "title",
      targets: 1
    }
  ];

  $('#dataList').DataTable({
    ajax: {
      url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos',
      type: 'GET',
      dataSrc: ''
    },
    bBootstrapLayout: true,
    columns: columnArray,
    columnDefs: [{
      render: function(data, type, row) {
        return data + ' (' + row['albumId'] + ')';
      },
      targets: 0
    }, {
      render: function(data, type, row) {
        var html = '<button>view</button>';

        return html;
      },
      targets: 2
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <head>

    <body>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
          <div>
            <table id="dataList" class="table" data-page-length="1" cellspacing="0" width="100%" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
```

### Having Custom button or form in row

In your datatable you can configure each column rendering logic. Like the case you are dealing, you want separate columns of button behave as form submission.
You  should tell this in `columnDefs` option as passing an array of definations.

In the code snippet above I also showed how you can achive that. In that example I added 3rd column (`target: 2`) by defining its rendering logic. In `render` callback you can return `html` that should be placed in that column. I only added `<button>view</button>` but as you see you can return any html like forms with input fields and buttons and whats not. `render` option takes a function that is provided with `data, type, row` parameters. Hence you can exploit these data for rendering your column html or any logic you what. Thats a lot of flexibility, isn't it ?

You will find a complementary guildline from this [columnDefs](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs) documentation.